# Add Context Link to Apollo Link after Client is created (after log-in)

Tags: javascript, react-apollo, apollo-client

I want to add a Context Link to an existing client's Apollo Link chain.

Here are two GitHub issues I've read through: [First](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/4990), [Second](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2897).

I do not want to use local storage to store the token as the docs show [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v3.0-beta/networking/authentication/).

I have an auth provider which stores my token. After storing my token I'd like to add a Context Link to the Apollo Client's links

```
  const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    const newHeaders = { ...headers };
    if (token) newHeaders.authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;

    return {
      headers: newHeaders,
    };
  });
```

I know I can access the client via `useClient`. **How do I append this link to the client's already existing from my component without doing it before making the client?**

`link: authLink.concat(httpLink)` or `link: authLink.concat(whateverLinksApolloHas)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there's a supported way of doing what you're trying to do. What you *can* do is initialize a new instance of `ApolloClient` and pass that to `ApolloProvider` instead. For example:

```
const [token, setToken] = useState(null)
const client = getClient(token) // adds the appropriate links as necessary

return <ApolloProvider client={client}><App/></ApolloProvider>
```

If you go this route and need to keep your cache when the token changes, make sure you utilize the same instance of `InMemoryCache` each time you create the client.

However, even this is probably overkill. There's no reason you can't always use `setContext`. You're already checking whether token exists before modifying the headers.

Comment: Agreed it's overkill. Now I'm trying to figure out how to access a context each time a request is made in my AuthLink. Replacing local storage with a context value with hooks.

Comment: I'm using localStorage because I'll need to store there eventually anyways to persist user log-in. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 10):

As of Apollo Client v3.0.0, you can now update the link chain using the `setLink` method on an Apollo Client after it has been created ([see Changelog Section v3](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md)).

> Apollo Client now supports setting a new ApolloLink (or link chain) after new ApolloClient() has been called, using the ApolloClient#setLink method.
> @hwillson in #6193

However, I have not found any documentation about it other than this though.

I wasn't able to just add a context link using `setContext`. Instead, it looks like it replaces the entire link chain, so here was my solution using `@apollo/client@3.2.5`.

```
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, NormalizedCacheObject } from '@apollo/client/core';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';
import fetchNewToken from 'your-token-function-file'

const replaceLinkChainOnClient = (client: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>, url: string) => {
    const httpLink: HttpLink = new HttpLink({
        uri: url
    });

    const link = setContext(async (operation, prevContext) => {
        const token = await fetchNewToken();
        return {
            ...prevContext,
            headers: {
                ...prevContext.headers,
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        };
    });
    client.setLink(link.concat(httpLink));
};
```